# PagerAdapter crashing

Tags: android, android-viewpager, layout-inflater, android-pageradapter

I have a pageradapter that i am using to display a slideshow of images but it crashes when i set a lower off screen limit.

Here is my code

```
public class ProjectPicturesAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<String> pictures;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final RequestManager glide;

public ProjectPicturesAdapter(RequestManager glide, LayoutInflater inflater, List<String> pictures) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.glide = glide;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View image = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_image, container, false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) image.findViewById(R.id.image);

    glide.load(pictures.get(position))
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.project_placeholder)
            .into(myImage);
    container.addView(myImage);
    return myImage;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
    container.removeView((View) view);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pictures.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

}
```

The way i am initializing the adapter is this

```
      ProjectPicturesAdapter picturesAdapter = new 
       ProjectPicturesAdapter(Glide.with(this), LayoutInflater.from(this), 
      images);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(picturesAdapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

If there are more than 2 images then it crashes,i could always increase the off screen limit but what happens if there are 20 pictures,i cannot keep the offscreen limit as 20.

My crash log is gives an error saying The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update `ProjectPicturesAdapter` as below:**

```
public class ProjectPicturesAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private List<String> pictures;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private final RequestManager glide;

public ProjectPicturesAdapter(RequestManager glide, LayoutInflater inflater, List<String> pictures) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.glide = glide;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_image, container, false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);

    glide.load(pictures.get(position))
            .centerCrop()
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.project_placeholder)
            .into(myImage);

    container.addView(view);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) {
    container.removeView((View) view);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pictures.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to show the carousel?
Just use this library and your problem will be solved https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by this:

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object view) 
{
    container.removeView((View) view);
}
```

I recommend to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of PagerAdapter.

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}
```

---

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());

mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: But i don't need to display fragments here , i just have a single image view layout